# Writing degrees Celsius in short hand ('c) in QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-expression, concatenation

There is a way to add something before the ' to indicate to QGIS that it is a string and not a column. In expression builder I simply want

```
"temperature" || ''C'
```

Comment: This answers my question.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. However, you need one extra backslash `\`. It is used to escape any special character.

```
"temperature" || '\'C'
```

Another option can be achieved via:

```
concat("temperature", char(39), 'C')
```

where [`char(39)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) - is the Apostrophe in Unicode.